# Directus access token for each user

Tags: authentication, access-token, directus

I need suggestions on this. We have apps that are fetching data to our API and we have also cms. So we're planning to migrate our system(CMS & API) to Directus. Now, we're discussing how we can manage to log in or create a token for each app to access the data(private) to Directus cms via Directus API.  We're thinking to create a user every time the app is installed in the device. What do you think of this? All suggestions are welcome? Thank you[image] :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good approach. You can use the "owner" field to limit permissions (CRUD) to certain items within a collection. You'll just want to have your external app be sure to set the appropriate owner when creating new "apps".

https://docs.directus.io/guides/permissions.html#accountability

There will be an even more granular "dynamic permissions" system in an upcoming version of Directus. This will make this sort of setup even easier/granular.

https://github.com/directus/api/issues/511